# topLayoutGuide moves after navigation controller push

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I've got a simple view controller hierarchy where one view controller is shown using a UINavigationController. In `viewDidLoad` it sets up its views with constraints. Before the view is fully visible (during animation), `topLayoutGuide` is the status bar, and it changes to be the bottom of the UINavigationBar when the view is fully on-screen. This results in views jumping around.

Removing the "Extend Edges Under Top Bars" option fixes this problem but makes the navigation bar have an unwanted gray gradient, which is only partially corrected with setting the navigation bar's `backgroundColor`.

Is there a way to have `topLayoutGuide` refer to the bottom of the navigation bar even during animation? This worked before, but it doesn't work with Xcode 8.0 in iOS 10.

Comment: You are just setting up constraints in `viewDidLoad`? This should work as you expect, without jumps. Could you please share the code you run?

Comment: @LeoNatan thanks for the tip. While simplifying my code to post here, I found the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

By commenting out large chunks of code, I found the culprit in one of the setup functions called from `viewDidLoad()`. Sorry my question doesn't include enough details to solve it. In case anyone sees this symptom in the future, here is the code which recreates the bug:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
    label.text = "Testing"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(label)
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The solution is to remove the `layoutIfNeeded()` call. Constraints take effect after `viewDidLoad()`, and calling `layoutIfNeeded()` within it will temporarily screw with `topLayoutGuide`.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, this was exactly the info I needed. I had code that had a copious amount of `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` calls that were also performed in viewDidLoad(). Removed those calls and voila!